# Could not delete from specified tables

Tags: ms-access

I need to delete all the data from Table1 that has a corresponding ID in Table2. I used:

```
DELETE Table1.*
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID
```

I ran it and got an error message "Could not delete from specified tables"

I also tried some suggestion I found here and changed the query to

```
DELETE Table1.*
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID=Table1.ID
```

But got the same eerror

Answer (score 4):

Apparently your JOIN has created a query that is not updateable. This is usually because one or both IDs are not primary keys or have no unique index.

More reasons can be found [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html) or [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html).

If this cannot be corrected, use an IN clause instead:

```sql
DELETE Table1.*
FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.ID IN (SELECT Table2.ID FROM Table2)
```

It will be slower than a INNER JOIN, but should work.

Comment: that didn't work either... I am suspecting some kind of a lock on the table because the same delete query as I used above worked for a different user from their machine

Comment: @ElenaDBA: so this user probably can't delete or edit anything? Does he have write access to the DB?

Comment: Yes. But I copied my database locally so that could have made a difference, I just can't seem to figure out what it is